# Converting a cURL command to Python's urllib2

Tags: python, curl, urllib2, urllib

guys!  I'm currently working with an API that uses the following cURL line:

```
curl -vF "files[]=@file.zip" "http://s5.example.com/123"
```

I'm not interested in using other libraries such as pycurl, because I really only need to convert a line or two.  I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is **urlopen** method of **urllib module**.. .

Syntax:
**urllib2.urlopen(url[, data][, timeout])**

data is the string specifying additional stuff to send to the server

Example:

```
import urllib
tlds = urllib.urlopen("http://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt").readlines()
```

this example shows a single line code to extract all tlds into a a list called tlds by crawling it from iana.org

For complex operations/options/parameters of urlopen method you can check the official documentation: http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html

Answer (score 2):

This request posts the file contents in a file upload field.
The http body of a POST request uploading a file is tricky to assemble - for ordinary text fields, one can just send a dictionary in the "data=" parameter to a urllib2.urlopen call, and the fields will be posted.

File uploads, though, need to send a complex http body, with customized headers.
I don't know if urllib2 can do this - but I found an example on how to do it using httplib and mimetypes (both part of Python's stdlib) - so you can pick the example code and reuse it on your project:

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/146306-http-client-to-post-using-multipartform-data/